Rotated page header
I have to comply with some arcane thesis requirements, among which are that any Tables to wide to fit on a page must be rotated and the page must be in landscape while the rest of the document is portrait. I also have to have a custom header which puts the current chapter at the left and the page number on the right.
I have made an MWE that almost does what I want, based on this answer:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{siunitx} % Required for units
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[paper=portrait,pagesize]{typearea}



\fancypagestyle{mylandscape}{
\fancyhf{} %Clears the header/footer
\fancyhead{% Footer
\makebox[\textwidth][l]{% Right
  \rlap{\hspace{-2cm}% Push out of margin by \footskip
    %\smash{% Remove vertical height
      \raisebox{4.87in}{% Raise vertically
        \rotatebox{90}{\textnormal{\leftmark} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \normalfont\small\slshape\thepage}}}}}%}% Rotate counter-clockwise
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule
}

\title{Table test}
\author{richardlfitzhugh }
\date{August 2024}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{landscape}
\thispagestyle{mylandscape}
\begin{table}
%\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Fun table!.}

\begin{tabular}{lr}

\toprule
Stuff & things \\ \midrule 
Thing1 & Thing2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}

\end{document}


However, the resulting header is bold, and I can't figure out for the life of me how to get it to be non-bold. \textnormal and \normalfont are used in the MWE but seem to have no effect.


It's not bold. It just looks bold.

\begin{tabular}{lr}[![enter image description here][2]][2] doesn't look right ....

@Werner Then why is it thicker than the rest of the font and thicker than the footnotes on the other pages?

@cfr Ah, that's why the first time I tried to include the screenshot it didn't work... Fixed, thanks.

are you viewing with fit width or similar? if so, the text will be smaller and, so, look denser/bolder.

I think you missed the square bracket.

Yes, you are right again. Now I got the square bracket. And no, I am not using fit width or similar. I am not sure how to get both pages in the MWE to the same scale if I upload them as images here, but the pages are the same size and yet the fonts are noticeably different if you compile it.

Note (because in a comment above you are comparing the weight of the page header and the weight of footnotes): Footnotes are not the same like page footer! For example footnotes are typeset in \footnotesize. Note also: In your current example the page numbers on landscape pages are \small but on other pages would be \normalsize.

unrelated but all these \  to produce a space looks odd. Why don't you use \hspace? Or put everything in a box and use \hfill \makebox[\textwidth]{a\hfill y} ?

Currently there is nothing in your example, that could be compared. If I extend your example a little bit, to have a comparable heading on the first page:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{siunitx} % Required for units
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[paper=portrait,pagesize]{typearea}



\fancypagestyle{mylandscape}{
\fancyhf{} %Clears the header/footer
\fancyhead{% Footer
\makebox[\textwidth][l]{% Right
  \rlap{\hspace{-2cm}% Push out of margin by \footskip
    %\smash{% Remove vertical height
      \raisebox{4.87in}{% Raise vertically
        \rotatebox{90}{\textnormal{\leftmark} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \normalfont\small\slshape\thepage}}}}}%}% Rotate counter-clockwise
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% No header rule
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}% No footer rule
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead{\textnormal{\leftmark}\hfill\normalfont\small\slshape\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\title{Table test}
\author{richardlfitzhugh }
\date{August 2024}

\begin{document}

\section{INTRODUCTION}

\begin{landscape}
  \thispagestyle{mylandscape}
\begin{table}
%\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Fun table!.}

\begin{tabular}{lr}

\toprule
Stuff & things \\ \midrule 
Thing1 & Thing2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}

and make two screenshots with scale factor 200%:


They look the same.
Note: The result depends on the PDF viewer and its settings, e.g., font anti-aliasing, scaling etc. and the resolution of the screen. Usually when printing with high resolution (and without scaling) the result is better comparable in such cases. IMHO this is independent from using TeX.

BTW: Because you are using package typearea, there would be an alternative to add landscape pages. In adaption of “How the margins can generally be retained when changing the paper format within a document” you could use that package to change the page orientation:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{siunitx} % Required for units
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage[paper=portrait]{typearea}

\newlength{\ptextwidth}
\newlength{\ptextheight}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{mylandscape}{%
  \endgroup
  \cleardoublepage
  \setlength{\ptextwidth}{\textwidth}%
  \setlength{\ptextheight}{\textheight}%
  \KOMAoptions{paper=landscape}%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{\ptextheight}%
  \setlength{\textheight}{\ptextwidth}%
  \activateareas
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\headwidth}{\textwidth}% note fancyhdr about the changed text width
  \def\@currenvir{mylandscape}%
  \edef\@currenvline{\on@line}%  
}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \KOMAoptions{paper=portrait}%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{\ptextwidth}%
  \setlength{\textheight}{\ptextheight}%
  \activateareas
}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead{\textnormal{\leftmark}\hfill\normalfont\small\slshape\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\title{Table test}
\author{richardlfitzhugh }
\date{August 2024}

\begin{document}

\section{INTRODUCTION}

\begin{mylandscape}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Fun table!.}

\begin{tabular}{lr}

\toprule
Stuff & things \\ \midrule 
Thing1 & Thing2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{mylandscape}

\end{document}

Something similar can be done using scrlayer-scrpage instead of fancyhdr:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{siunitx} % Required for units
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[paper=portrait]{typearea}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{}
\newlength{\ptextwidth}
\newlength{\ptextheight}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{mylandscape}{%
  \endgroup
  \cleardoublepage
  \setlength{\ptextwidth}{\textwidth}%
  \setlength{\ptextheight}{\textheight}%
  \KOMAoptions{paper=landscape}%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{\ptextheight}%
  \setlength{\textheight}{\ptextwidth}%
  \activateareas
  \begingroup
  \def\@currenvir{mylandscape}%
  \edef\@currenvline{\on@line}%  
}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \KOMAoptions{paper=portrait}%
  \setlength{\textwidth}{\ptextwidth}%
  \setlength{\textheight}{\ptextheight}%
  \activateareas
}
\makeatother

\title{Table test}
\author{richardlfitzhugh }
\date{August 2024}

\begin{document}

\section{INTRODUCTION}

\begin{mylandscape}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Fun table!.}

\begin{tabular}{lr}

\toprule
Stuff & things \\ \midrule 
Thing1 & Thing2 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{mylandscape}

\end{document}

Here the manual adaption of the header width is not needed.
Both examples result in

